# Tablesorter scroll not working

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table and need to enable the scrollable option. I tried the below code but I dont see the scrollable option enabled at all.

```
$("#ticket-table").tablesorter({
             sortList: [],
             headers: {
                 // 2: {
                 //     //sorter: 'time',
                 //     //sorter:'my_date_column' 
                 //     //dateFormat: "ddd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                 //     //sorter: 'monthDayYear'
                 // },
                 10: {
                     sorter: false
                 },
                 16: {
                     sorter: false
                 }
             },
             theme: "bootstrap",
             headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
             widgets: ['uitheme','scroller'],
             widgetOptions: {
                  scroller_height : 20,
      // scroll tbody to top after sorting
      scroller_upAfterSort: true,
      // pop table header into view while scrolling up the page
      scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
      // In tablesorter v2.19.0 the scroll bar width is auto-detected
      // add a value here to override the auto-detected setting
      scroller_barWidth : null
      // scroll_idPrefix was removed in v2.18.0
      // scroller_idPrefix : 's_'
            }
         });
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting the scroller_height to a number bigger than 20... please modify this demo to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ft3qyjns/

Comment: Its a jquery generated table..I have added the current look of the table..Im adding the 4 test columns and it just squeezes the table instead of making a scrollable..Im using bootstrap theme..The table is contained in a <div>

Comment: Try the css from the demo I shared... it keeps the cells from resizing beyond a certain point.

Comment: I had a fixed-width table..After I removed, it worked...Thanks